# Can "das" be both singular and plural?

Tags: word-usage

A German friend wrote once

> “Sind das Kängurus im Hintergrund?”

I would have thought that the question should have been

> “Sind sie Kängurus im Hintergrund?”

But who am I to argue with a native speaker (I am an Australian who learnt German at school and who enjoys the complexity of the German language).

Comment: Well, by the way, as there are no Känguruhs in Germany, the sentence should properly be *Sind das Rehe im Hintergrund?*

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann But there are many in Australia! Read the question carefully.

Comment: @Eller  Now, that's a question: do we want a literal translation, or do we want a culturally adjusted one?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann There is nothing to adjust. Think about it: an Australian guy shows his German friend a photo (obviously it is more probable a photo of an Australian landscape, not of some Schwarzwaldlandschaft). So the German friend asks "Sind das Kängurus im Hintergrund?" Or do you think German friend cannot recognize Kängurus and thinks those are _Rehe_? Well, that might be a cultural adjustment. Not a flattering one for the German friend though.

Comment: @Eller  - It was a joke. I tried to transfer the scene into a (stereo)typical German environment.

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to another peculiarity of my mother tongue. "Sind das" is definitely correct but it beats me as to why. The answer I liked best so far is the one by Tom Au in the linked questions stating that it is a placeholder and that the verb follows the "complement" subject.

Comment: "Sind dies" would be fine, too, and also not flexed ("ist dies") unlike English "is this" / "are these". "Sind sie Kängurus im Hintergrund?" and "Are they kangaroos in the background?" both sound slightly wrong to me, btw.

Answer (score 19):

The sentence with "das" is right.

To explain, note that "das" is not an article in this case, so it is not "das Kaengurus", that would indeed be wrong. Instead, here "das" is a pronoun that can be translated as "that", as in

> Are that kangaroos in the background?

For a long list of examples of der/die/das as a pronoun in German, you can look at the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/der_Demonstrativpronomen).

If you want to use an article here, that would be

> Are that the kangaroos in the background?
>   Sind das die Kaengurus im Hintergrund?

This implies that you already know (of) the kangaroos, e.g. because you mentioned before that you have seen some on your trips.

Comment: The question was not about *das* being an article or pronoun but why the singular is used instead of the plural.

Comment: Sagt man nicht eher "Are those kangaroos?"

Comment: @Rha there is no plural of "das" in German. In this case "das" points to a group of objects. You could replace the kangaroos with anything and it would (mostly) still be right. Also the second sentence just sounds wrong for native Germans.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Not to me. Imagine a picture of costumed people and someone asking: "Sind das die Kinder im Hintergrund?"

Comment: So you wouldn't ask "Sind die Kaengurus I'm Hintergrund" for "are those kangaroos in the background?"

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I mean the second sentence OP posted `“Sind sie Kängurus im Hintergrund?”``. This one sounds very wrong

Comment: Note also that for this use of "das" the German might in principle refer to an unidentifiable smudge in the background, in which case the "that" is totally right ;) In general "das" is simply referring to a shape/area/thing - it might be a single object or multiple ones, but since the asker isn't sure about the identification at the time of asking it's just an unidentified something, thus no plural required.

Comment: But if we're referring to a smudge on the image, wouldn't we say "Ist das..."?

Comment: @BruceWayne Depends. If you mean "Are those kangaroos in the background" in the sense of "Those kangaroos we talked about, are they in the backgorund?", it would be, but if you mean "Are those things in the background kangaroos", you'd say "Sind das...".

Answer (score 4):

You are probably confused by the apparent lack of *congruence*. However, the *demonstrative pronoun* in the construct in question is "das" (or "dies") without congruence:

> Dies  (or "das", but not "dieser") ist Onkel Herbert.
>   Das (or "dies", but not "diese") ist Tante Hedwig.
>   Das (or "dies", but not "diese") sind Tick, Trick und Track.

But compare

> Das sind meine drei Kängurus. Dieses [Känguru] hier kann gut boxen und diese beiden sind noch ganz jung

Answer (score 3):

I actually don't know on what rule this is based upon, but here are a few further examples:

> Sind das Kängurus im Hintergrund? 
>   Ja, das sind Kängurus im Hintergrund. 
>   Das sind Kängurus und das ist ein Eichhörnchen. 
>   Ist das alles? 
>   Das kann man so nicht sagen.

*"Das"* verhält sich hier eher wie ein *"hier"*, *"dies(e)"* oder *"dort"*. Es ist also nicht der bestimmte Artikel, sondern vergleichbar mit "*that/this/these*" im Englischen.

Comment: Saying "indeed, this is possible", what are you referring by "this"??

Comment: To the question title.

Comment: So , "Can “das” be both singular and plural?" - "yes, "das" can be singlar and plural"? Sorry, that is wrong.

Comment: Maybe the "be" is a bit confusing there. "Das" can refer to singular and plural, but it "is" not in plural. I just delete that sentence..

Answer (score 0):

As Dirk Liebhold wrote "das" is no article in this sentence. It does not refer to the "Kängurus" but to the scene the speaker sees. There is only one scene he means. As an article "das" is singular, every time.

Comment: Eine Szene wäre ein Sonnenuntergang, oder vielleicht bei Kängurus ein Paarungstanz. "Die Szene" ist auch Einzahl, und dann wäre es nicht _Sind das ..._ sondern _Ist das ..._. "Ist das Paarunngstanz?" o. "Ist das der Paarungstanz der Kängurus?" Das _das_ könnte man durch _dies_ ersetzen.

Comment: "Das" absolutely refers to the "Kängurus" here. The same way you could say "sind das meine 3 bestellten Kuchenstücke?" oder "sind das deine drei Kinder" oder "sind das die Nachbarn?". There does not need to be more context (as in a "scene").

Comment: Wer oder was sind möglicherweise Kängurus? "das"
Wer oder was sind das? Es sind Kängurus.

Comment: I don't see a question with the answer "das Kängurus". Thus I'd say "das" is not the article of "Kängurus". I could say "Sind das, worauf ich mich beziehe, Kängurus" and called the reference a scene.