# Warum wurde "es werden" in diesem Satz benutzt?

Tags: verb, pronoun, grammatical-number, tense, conjugation

Ich kann nicht verstehen, warum im folgenden Satz das Verb *werden* im Plural konjugiert wurde.

**Es werden nur noch 12 Wörter jeden Tag sein.**

Ich glaube, der Satz bezieht sich auf Futur I und gemäß dem Subjekt *es* müsste hier *wird* verwendet werden.

Comment: Der vorige Satz wäre zum Verständnis hilfreich, aber wahrscheinlich waren es zuvor 15 oder 20 Wörter.

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55042/why-use-the-plural-conjugate-of-the-verb-in-this-case same question

Comment: Das Subjekt ist "12 Wörter". Daher der Plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Frage ist, wonach das finite Verb in einem deutschen Satz sich in Person und Numerus richtet. In fast allen Fällen ist die Antwort: Nach dem Subjekt.

Das Subjekt ist meistens daran zu erkennen, dass es im Satz als Nominativ auftritt. Es gibt jedoch Verben wie die Kopulaverben *sein, werden* und *bleiben*, die sich außer dem Subjekt mit einem zweiten Nominativ verbinden können:

> **Der Walter** [Subjekt im Nominativ] ist **unser bester Fahrer** [Nominativ 2].

Dieser zweite Nominativ wird in den Grammatiken unterschiedlich bezeichnet. In älteren Grammatiken hieß er *Prädikatsnomen* oder *Gleichsetzungsnominativ*, heute heißt er bei  [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativum#Pr%C3%A4dikatsnomen) *Prädikativ(um)*, bei [Grammis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/202) *Prädikativkomplement*, in der Duden-Grammatik (1) ebenfalls **Prädikativ**. Die zuletzt genannten Begriffe sind jedoch Oberbegriffe und bezeichnen eine ganze Klasse von Ausdrücken, in denen unter anderem auch Adjektive, Adverbien und Präpositionalphrasen vorkommen. In der Form von einem Substantiv im Nominativ spricht man von einem *prädikativen Nominativ*.(2)

Für das angegebene Beispiel heißt das:

> **Es** [*Subjekt*] werden **nur noch 12 Wörter** [*prädikativer Nominativ*] jeden Tag sein.

Erstaunlich ist, dass in diesem Satz das finite Verb *werden* nicht mit dem Subjekt *es*, sondern mit dem prädikativen Nominativ *12 Wörter* "kongruiert" (= zusammenpasst). Das wäre auch in anderen Zeitformen der Fall:

> Es **sind** 12 Wörter.

Dazu schreibt die Duden-Grammatik von 2006 auf S. 1026:

(Es hat sich) "gezeigt, dass der prädikative Nominativ den Numerus des finiten Verbs mit beeinflusst. Bemerkbar wird dies jeweils, wenn sich Subjekt und prädikativer Nominativ im Numerus unterscheiden. (...) Wo das der Fall ist, steht das finite Verb gewöhnlich im Plural:

(...) [Das] *sind* [meine einzigen Ferien]. (...) [Welches] *sind* [seine wichtigsten Erfolge]?"

Es bleibt damit festzuhalten:

> **Im Deutschen gibt es Sätze, in denen das Verb *nicht* mit dem Subjekt, sondern mit dem prädikativen Nominativ kongruiert.**

Die Struktur wird vielen deutschen Kindern aus Märchen gut bekannt sein, denn einige Märchen fangen nach diesem Muster an:

> Es waren einmal ein König und eine Königin, die hatten eine schöne Tochter...

oder in der bekannten Volksliedzeile

> Es waren zwei Königskinder / die hatten einander so lieb.

Ein solcher Kongruenz"fehler" betrifft manchmal auch die Personalform:

> **Der hier** ganz links auf dem Foto **bin** ich.

Da man zwischen Subjekt und prädikativem Nominativ wegen der Kasusgleichheit (beides im Nominativ) nicht klar unterscheiden kann, könnte man einfach den prädikativen Nominativ zum Subjekt umdeklarieren. Das würde jedoch nicht alle Fälle lösen und zudem Deutschlerner dabei beeinträchtigen, eine stabile grammatische Kategorie "prädikativer Nominativ" auszubilden.

Obwohl die genannten Kongruenz-Widersprüche im System stören, sind sie psychologisch verständlich, denn es handelt sich meist um Sätze mit dem "Leer-Subjekt" *es* als syntaktischem Platzhalter und einem eigentlich inhaltlich gemeinten Quasi-Subjekt, das syntaktisch nur noch als prädikativer Nominativ auftreten kann, da die Subjektrolle schon vergeben ist. Viele derartige Sätze kann man umstellen:

> es kamen 10 Leute
>
> 10 Leute kamen

so dass auf der syntaktischen Ebene die "natürliche Ordnung" wiederhergestellt ist. Aber die Aussageabsicht der beiden Sätze ist nicht identisch: Im ersten Satz geht es um die Anzahl der Leute, im zweiten darum, dass diese Leute überhaupt kamen und nicht zu Hause blieben oder man hat (sprechsprachlich), mit sehr starker Betonung auf *10 Leute*, eine noch stärkere Heraushebung der Personenzahl als im ersten Satz.

---

<sup>(1) Duden. Die Grammatik (= Duden Band 4), Mannheim 2006, S. 798  -  (2) ebenda S. 803</sup>

Comment: (1) *der hier bin ich*: Warum soll *der hier* das Subjekt sein? Wie kann ich das erkennen? (2) Ist das *es* im Satz des Fragestellers wirklich leer? Wie ist es in dem folgenden Beispiel? *In einem Waldstück hat er die Bäume mit einem roten Ring markiert, die bleiben können. Es sind wenige.*

Comment: Grammatische Intuition. Ich stelle mir nicht vor, dass bei '_die Dame in Rot ist unsere Tante Irma und der mit der Mütze bin ich_' die Subjekte die Plätze tauschen, aber es kann auch beide Male das Prädikativ vorne stehen. "Beweisen" lässt sich das nicht. (2) In deinem Beispiel hat _es_ auch einen pronominalen, rückbezüglichen Charakter, in dem von mir gemeinten '_es kamen nur drei Leute_' nicht, da ist das _es_ unpersönlich und semantisch leer.

Answer (score 6):

*Werden* bezieht sich auf *12 Wörter*. Der Satz sagt aus, dass die 12 Wörter etwas sein werden.
*12 Wörter* ist Plural, daher die Pluralform des Verbs.

#### zu den Fragen aus Kommentaren

> Meine eigentliche Frage ist, Warum in erstem Satz das Verb nicht gemäß dem Subjekt konjugiert wird.

Das Wort *sein* bezieht sich nicht auf *es* oder den *Tag* sondern auf die *12 Wörter*. Diese sind Plural, daher steht auch das Verb im Plural.

Beispiel

- 15 Gäste kommen zur Party - es werden 15 Gäste kommen.
- 19 Autos stehen auf dem Parkplatz, ein weiteres kommt dazu - es werden 20 Autos auf dem Parkplatz stehen.
- Das Beispiel aus der Frage klingt unvollständig, da fehlt noch eine weitere Information. Wenn ich einen Satz bilde der etwas mehr aussagt sieht er so aus.
  Bis heute schreiben wir 15 Wörter pro Tag, ab morgen nur noch 12 - heute sind es 15 Wörter (die wir schreiben), ab morgen werden es nur noch 12 Wörter sein.

> Ich kann andere Beispiele nennen, in denen diese Regel gilt. Zum Beispiel: *Es gibt* 12 Wörter.

*Es gibt* sieht für mich nach einer Sonderform aus. Hier bezieht sich das *geben* nicht direkt auf die Wörter, sondern auf das *es*. Nicht die Wörter geben etwas, sondern das Konstrukt *Es gibt* drückt aus dass das nachfolgend erklärte existiert. Also: Hier sind 12 Wörter.

Comment: Danke für Ihre schnelle Antwort. Können wir dann den Satz so umschreiben? "Nur noch 12 wörter werden sein." In diesem Fall ist "es" entfällt und "12 Wörter" ist Subjekt. Deshalb ist es normaler, das Verb im Plural zu konjugieren.

Comment: Meine eigentliche Frage ist, Warum in erstem Satz das Verb nicht gemäß dem Subjekt konjugiert wird. Ich kann andere Beispiele nennen, in denen diese Regel gilt. Zum Beispiel: "Es gibt 12 Wörter."

Comment: @Bornak Man kann das "es" in diesem Fall weglassen, dadurch wird es aber nicht normaler sondern ungewohnter. Die Formulierung "Es werden ... sein" ist üblicher. Zum Beispiel "es werden 15 Gäste sein". Das Beispiel aus der Frage klingt schon seltsam, das im Kommentar klingt noch komischer. Was werden die Wörter sein? Da fehlt noch eine Information aus einem vorherigen Satz. Davon hängt ab, wie der aktuelle Satz am besten formnuliert wird.

Answer (score 3):

Die [Kopulaverben](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)) *sein, werden, bleiben* verbinden ein Subjekt mit einem ([prädikativen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression#Predicative_(adjectival_or_nominal))) Objekt (üblicherweise *Prädikativ* oder *Prädikativkomplement* genannt; zur Terminologie siehe [hier](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/202)). Aufgrund der freien Wortstellung des Deutschen kann das Objekt dem Subjekt vorangehen oder folgen.

> Der Schuldige bin ich.
>   Ich bin der Schuldige.

Wie die Subjekt-Verb-Kongruenz deutlich macht, ist *ich* in beiden Fällen das Subjekt und *der Schuldige* das Objekt. Nach der gleichen Logik ist *12 Wörter* das Subjekt des Ausgangsbeispiels.

Zur korrekten Interpretation des Objekts *es* benötigt man wahrscheinlich ein bißchen mehr Kontext. Zum Beispiel:

> Bisher haben wir jeden Tag 24 Wörter gelernt. Jetzt werden es nur noch 12 Wörter sein.

Dann ist klar, daß *es* die Zahl der Wörter, die täglich gelernt werden, bezeichnet.

Comment: Die Bezeichnung 'prädikatives Objekt' finde ich ungewöhnlich. Ich kannte bis jetzt die Begriffe 'Prädikativ(um)', wobei ein Prädikativ durch ein Nomen/Substantiv oder durch ein (prädikatives) Adjektiv realisiert sein kann. Außerdem ist zwischen Subjekts- und Objektsprädikativen zu unterscheiden, früher auch Gleichsetzungnominative und Gleichsetzungsakkusative genannt. Beim Deutschlernen ist die Unterscheidung zwischen Subjektsprädikativ und Objekt elementar, weil erstere als Substantive im Nominativ auftreten, letztere in den anderen Kasus. 'Prädikatives Objekt' vermischt beides.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Terminologie ist in der Sprachwissenschaft und Sprachvermittlung immer eine Qual! Sowohl *Prädikativergänzung* als auch *Prädikativkomplement* sind übliche Begriffe; ich habe nur den zweiten Teil durch *Objekt* ersetzt, weil ich dachte, daß das der bekanntere Begriff ist. Einem Objekt wird immer ein bestimmter Kasus zugewiesen; das möglicherweise Neue (und hoffentlich nicht Verwirrende) ist allenfalls, daß der Nominativ als Objektkasus auftreten kann.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Argumentation. Ich würde dennoch in so einem Fall das 'Objekt' zumindest in Anführungszeichen setzen, denn es handelt sich um einen quasi-metaphorischen Gebrauch. Aufgrund der starken Assoziation von 'Objekt' mit 'Akkusativ' und 'Dativ würde ich andererseits ein Prädikativ nicht so bezeichnen, weil dies das Verständnis der Sonderstellung der Kopulaverben mit ihrer 
Forderung nach nominativischen Ergänzungen blockiert bzw. erschwert. Im Anfänger-Sprachunterricht nenne ich die substantivischen Prädikative "Nominativ 2".

Comment: Ich würde behaupten, *es* könnte auch Dativ-Objekt sein, wie in "Dem ist nicht so" ~ "Es ist nicht so". Das ist natürlich zweifelhaft. Die Frage ist kompliziert. Das erklärt, weshalb diese immer wieder gestellt wird.

Comment: @vectory: Ich vermute stark, dass dieses _dem_ syntaktisch eine ähnliche Rolle spielt wie _an dem_ in "_es ist nicht an dem, dass ..._" = "es trifft nicht zu, dass ...". Hier ist das Prädikativ ein Nebensatz, der mit Hilfe einer Präpositionalphrase als Korrelat eingebettet wird. Es könnte auch heißen "_es ist nicht so, dass ..._", also eine Art Modalergänzung wie in "_ist ja hier nicht wie bei armen Leuten_". _Dem_ in _dem ist nicht so_ ist allerdings nicht Korrelat, es steht 'frei', ist dabei nicht Subjekt, für mich am ehesten ein 'freier Dativ' oder eine verhinderte Präpositionalphrase.

Comment: (... Fortsetzung)  Ob etwas Subjekt oder Prädikativ ist, ist aufgrund er im Deutschen variablen Wortstellung manchmal nicht zu entscheiden: _Herr Müller ist unser neuer Chef._ Ob _dem_ in Deinem Satz als Prädikativ aufgefasst werden kann, ist für mich fraglich. Auch in _mir ist kalt_ ist _mir_ weder Subjekt noch Prädikativ: Prädikativ ist _kalt_ und das Subjekt ist getilgt wie in _da wurde schlecht gearbeitet_ Letztlich lassen sich solche Sätzen mit syntaktischen Kategorien an der Oberfläche nicht vollständig analysieren. _Dem ist nicht so_ ist einerseits erstarrte Wendung, damit lexikalisiert

Comment: (... Fortsetzung) und nur in engem Rahmen variierbar, und in seiner Grundsubstanz ist es ein unpersönlicher Ausdruck (_es ist nicht an dem, was zuvor behauptet wurde / es verhält sich damit anders_). Seiner oberflächlichen Struktur nach ähnelt er _dem ist nichts hinzuzufügen_, aber hier gibt es ein richtiges Subjekt (nichts) und ein echtes Dativobjekt. - - - Übrigens gibt es umgangssprachlich auch Dative als Quasi-Prädikative: _Wem ist die Jacke hier?_ Der Dativ hat ja zuweilen eine possessive Funktion.

Comment: @RalfJoerres, ich bezog Stellung zu DavidVogt's "Nominativ als Objektkasus". Mit Subjekt/Objekt hatte das erstmal nichts zu tun. Ich würde einfach das *so* als nominatives Relativpronomen sehen, da kommt es ursprünglich wohl her, früher. Das passt dann als Subjekt. Hattest du das übersehen? *mir ist kalt* gibt wie viele wetter-verben einfach keinen Täter an

Comment: @vectory: Danke für den Tipp, jetzt sehe ich, dass David Vogt eine unvollständige Antwort gegeben hat.